# Python replace all occurrences found using regex

Tags: python, regex

In python, trying to replace all occurrence of a string found using regex such as:

```
'10am 11pm 13am 14pm 4am'
```

becomes

```
'10 am 11 pm 13 am 14 pm 4 am'
```

I tried

```
re.sub('([0-9].*)am(.*)', r'\1 am \2', ddata)
```

But this only replaces the last occurrence.

and

```
import re
regex = re.compile('([0-9].*)am+', re.S)
myfile =  '10am 11pm 13am 14pm 4am'
myfile2 = regex.sub(lambda m: m.group().replace(r'am',r" am ",1), myfile)
print(myfile2)
```

only replaces the first occurence of 'am'

Expected results to me `'10 am 11pm 13 am 14pm 4 am'`

Comment: `(\d{1,2})(?=[ap]m)` replace with `\1 ` ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/BwUAL7/3)) **or** `(\d{1,2})([ap]m)` replace with `\1 \2`([see here](https://regex101.com/r/BwUAL7/4))

Comment: I think I was not clear in my I was using reg ex in this case. Imagine the sentence: "the amphitheater opens at 10am-11am and 3pm-7pm" - we want to make sure NOT to replace 'am' in amphitheater.

Comment: The real question is do you really want to change that sentence/example? Given the conditions you set you **CAN** use this, but it's going to be ugly. `>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)([ap]m)', r' \1', 'the amphitheater opens at 10am-11am and 3pm-7pm')`... `#OUTPUT: 'the amphitheater opens at 10 am-11 am and 3 pm-7 pm'`

Comment: @FailSafe came to the same conclusion.  positive lookbehind works but sentence looks ugly.  does the OP want something like `10 am - 11 am and 3 pm - 7 pm`?  now that is another question altogether from the original post. :)

Comment: @FailSafe this sentence transformation is NOT meant for human consumption so yes I really do want to do this.

Comment: @SanV Haha, indeed. I kind of thought of the same thing so I made it just in case. Depends on what jvence wants. `>>> re.sub(r'((?<=\d)[ap]m|(?<=m)\-|(?<=\-)\d)', r' \1', 'the amphitheater opens at 10am-11am and 3pm-7pm')` ............ `#OUTPUT: 'the amphitheater opens at 10 am - 11 am and 3 pm - 7 pm'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the work:

```
import re
myfile =  '10am 11pm 13am 14pm 4am'
re.sub(r'(\d+)(am|pm)', r'\1 \2', myfile)
```

Here is the test output:

```
>>> import re
>>> myfile =  '10am 11pm 13am 14pm 4am'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)(am|pm)', r'\1 \2', myfile)
'10 am 11 pm 13 am 14 pm 4 am'
>>>
```

EDIT: Here is the output of the same solution dealing with the string you posted in the comments:

```
>>> import re
>>> myfile = 'The amphitheater opens at 10am-11am and 3pm-7pm'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)(am|pm)', r'\1 \2', myfile)
'The amphitheater opens at 10 am-11 am and 3 pm-7 pm'
>>>
```

Comment: I think I was not clear in my I was using reg ex in this case. Imagine the sentence: "the amphitheater opens at 10am-11am and 3pm-7pm" - we want to make sure NOT to replace 'am' in amphitheater.

Comment: @jvence, did you check my answer? It address that without any problem since I'm matching numbers followed by am or pm, without spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use capture groups for both the digits and the "am" or "pm" string and then just substitute with a space between the groups.

```
import re

s = '10am 11pm 13am 14pm 4am'

subbed = re.sub(r'(\d+)([ap]m)', r'\1 \2', s)
print(subbed)
# 10 am 11 pm 13 am 14 pm 4 am
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted a solution using regex instead of a plain string `replace` method as mentioned above, you could use the below snippet.

```
import re
myfile = '10am 11pm 13am 14pm 4am'
myfile2 = re.sub(r'(\d+)(am)', lambda m: '{} {}'.format(*m.groups()), myfile, 0)
print(myfile2)
```

Comment: Why introduce ```lambda``` and ```str.format``` when you are already using ```re.sub```?

Comment: @accdias that is needed since you need to know the digit and the am/pm info. This solution is flexible to handle both am and pm  info. My initial snippet had the second part of regex as `(am|pm)` which was later edited to include only `am` since thats what the OP asked for. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I see what you are referring to here, instead of lambda, you can directly use back references like `r'\1 \2'`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without using re:

```
'10am 11pm 13am 14pm 4am'.replace('a',' a').replace('p',' p')  

## Output: '10 am 11 pm 13 am 14 pm 4 am'
```

Comment: Thank you for not using a solution that's more complicated than needed. Hate to say that I wonder if this question will get -1'ed? Anyway, I'm gonna post this under yours if he wants regex because a full answer isn't needed at all here. `>>> re.sub(r'(a|p)', r' \1', '10am 11pm 13am 14pm 4am')` ................ `#OUTPUT:` `'10 am 11 pm 13 am 14 pm 4 am'`

Comment: @FailSafe Thanks and your regex pattern is the most concise and apt among the others on this page.  Hopefully the OP takes notice of it.

Comment: @FailSafe See comment added above about the sentence: "the amphitheater opens at 10am-11am and 3pm-7pm"

Comment: This will have collateral effects with strings out of that pattern.